# Single AJAX Action Multiple views rails best practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

With my current project I'm running into a situation and trying to figure out the best practices.

Let's say there is a dashboard view and a tasks view. All the Task CRUD actions can be done in either view.

The containers for displaying forms and the container for listing tasks have different names on each view.

I found 3 solutions but am not sure which is the best practice:

1. Separate routes for one view: i.e. new_task_dashboard_ iew_path - not very restful but new.js and new_dashboard_view.js are separated for HTML manipulation
2. Pass a param[:view] to the AJAX request and then add an if statement within the new.js to indicate which container to update ie. (if params[:view] == 'dashboard' kind of statement)
3. Just leave the new.js - the containers that don't exist on the DOM won't get updated - only the containers that exist will be updated

All 3 work but as a new rails user I'm trying to figure out what the most appropriate approach is. Or maybe there's a better practice that I'm not aware of?

Comment: not sure if this should be 'answered' or just commented since it is subjective to your design approach...but what experience has taught me(painfully) is that it would be better to have separate controllers(#1) and then leverage controller concerns/modulurizing your js/partials/shared views to keep it DRY.  I find trying to simplifying to the extent of sharing controllers for different concepts will end up causing you more pain down the road when you go to add more behavior/understand your code.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I had been trying #2 for the most part and was struggling when I went back to change views etc. Sounds like there's no obvious "Rails Way" but that some ways can be less painful!

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up I thought I'd post the direction I decided to go in incase it helps any other new rails users.

To follow on dstull's comment I found that passing an extra param such as view worked initially but caused big problems later on. Also running through lots of conditionals based on an extra param was resource intensive in comparison to other options.

In this case namespaces seemed to work the best for the design. For example:

```
#config/routes.rb
namespace :dashboard_view do
  resources :tasks
end

namespace :task_view do 
  resources :tasks
end
```

I then had separate controllers/views/javascript for each of my views. For example:

```
#views/dashboard_view/tasks/new.js
$('#dashboard-task-form-container).html('<%= j render "form" %>');

#views/task_view/tasks/new.js
$('#task-form-container).html('<%= j render "form" %>');

#controllers/dashboard_view/tasks_controller.rb
class DashboardView::TasksController < ApplicationController
  ...

#controllers/task_view/tasks_controller.rb
class TaskView::TasksController < ApplicationController
  ...
```

Although it seems obvious in retrospect as a new rails developer I had a hard time figuring out to structure things.

Hopefully this helps someone else!